# Custom Auth Middleware not redirecting properly for unauthorized user

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-middleware

I have created a custom auth controller for recognising unauthorized user and redirect them to login path. If logged in the middlewre is working absolutely fine, but showing error if not logged in. Here is my code

### Middleware:

```
    class CheckUserAuthenticated
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if(auth()->check()) {
            $user_id =  auth()->user()->id;
            define('authenticated_user_id' ,$user_id);
            return $next($request);
        }
        return redirect('login'); // this code is not working
    }
}
```

## Error:

[image]

Comment: Did you make sure that that the code beneath `auth()->check()` is invoked and not any other middleware? I just want to make sure that this class is the one that is working.

Comment: Yes. That class is working fine. Just not working outside part of the condition, i.e. `return redirect('login');`

Answer (score 0):

try this hope it help

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if(auth()->check()) {
        $user_id =  auth()->user()->id;
        define('authenticated_user_id' ,$user_id);
        return $next($request);
    }
    return redirect('/login');  OR   return redirect(route('login'));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```php
class CheckUserAuthenticated
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if(auth()->check()) {
            $user_id =  auth()->user()->id;
            define('authenticated_user_id' ,$user_id);
            return $next($request);
        }
        // return redirect('login'); // this code is not working

        return redirect()->guest('/login');
    }
}
```

`redirect()->guest()` will redirect if there is no authenticated user.

Example: If an authenticated user is logged in, it won't redirect them as they aren't a guest. If a user isn't logged in, the redirect will happen.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is in circular routing, you are calling from one route, and then return to the same route from the middleware, so your request never reaches the endpoint.

if you call middleware on the...

Route::get('login')->middleware('auth);

...then middleware can not route to 'login' on the fail...

return redirect('login');

... because it will create the loop that never ends. The middleware should reroute to something else, or be placed on other route like 'admin'...

You probably have the middleware on the 'login', that creates the loop, just remove it.